# MySQL and several concats?

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation

I have this query:

```
SELECT concat('insert into catalog_category_entity_text (value) values(test) where value_id = ', value_id)
FROM catalog_category_entity_text
WHERE value LIKE '%category-slider%'
```

The result looks like this for example:

```
insert into catalog_category_entity_text (value) values(test) where value_id = 15
```

Now, what I wanto is to replace the *test* with another value like value_id. In this case, the column is called *value*. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
SELECT concat('insert into catalog_category_entity_text (value) values(\'',value,'\') where value_id = ', value_id)
FROM catalog_category_entity_text
WHERE value LIKE '%category-slider%'
```